# identity server and owin context configuration

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin, identityserver3

Before id server I had lines like this in my code:

```
// Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

but with the changes to user identity with id server I do ot have the create methods based on the code I got from the sample.
but now if I try to call  `.GetUserManager<Infrastructure.ApplicationUserManager>();` I get `null`.
how do I fix this ? do I need to create new .create methods and put back that code or is there a configuration item in identity server I have missed ?

My `/token` works and when I call web api I have the user id / identity,
but I need to call the user manager and role manager from some things that I need in the web api logic.